# java - debugging "Watch" set up for a string, weird values for charAt(0)

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, char

I'm facing a weird behavior using java to examine a String whilst debugging in IntelliJ.

When I have stopped at a breakpoint, the "Watch" for `result.charAt(0)` contains weird values which I do not understand.

If `sresutl = 30` why is it then that `sresutl.charAt(0) = '3' 51` (note the extra 51) - where did that come from?

(I know it is not particularly elegant code, but it's just for educational purposes so don't worry :) )

[image]

Comment: for those downvoting, could you please at least say why... if you think you are so good why dont you just answer the question. I believe this is a valid question.

Comment: `(int) '3' == 51`. It's the codepoint value of the character.

Comment: Thanks. stupid mistake, appendToTail is expecting an int.. Im passing in  char.. the IDE didnt warn me.. I have to cast it (again, not particularly elegant, I'm trying to test something quickly)

Comment: "if you think you are so good..." Whilst I haven't downvoted the question, please bear in mind that comments like this attract more downvotes. Being rude to people you are asking for help is rarely a good strategy.

Comment: It was not directed to you @AndyTurner, sorry if it looked like that. It was aim to those people that downvoted a perfectly valid question without no explanation whatsoever. we are all programmers and have all been in situation where you are so caught up in what you are doing that you miss silly errors like these... I dont care about reputation or downvotes, it's just the attitude that bugs me a bit... I honestly think this is a valid question.

Comment: @feresr I have actually edited your question to make it more clear, both in the title and the introduction text. Please see how I edited it - the previous revision of the question perhaps wasn't so good, that's why it attracted downvotes. Now that it specifically talks about using the debugger, a breakpoint, and a String watch, I think the quesiton is more valid. I also think it is a perfectly valid question, and I gave it +1.

Comment: Thanks, the edited question does looks better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string value is `"30"` and you get the first character of it which is `'3'`and `'3'` is equivalent to `51` in ASCII code, hence you get `51`.

It is not an extra. It is the equivalent ASCII value of `'3'`.

Comment: Thanks!, that makes a lot of sense :) Will accept this answer as soon as I can.

Comment: @feresr Glad to help, do not worry too much on the down votes as long as you clear your doubts ;)